# Can I create a dynamic, Ajax widget as a Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

I'm confused by the many different ways to extend Facebook.

My Q: Can I create a Facebook App in an iframe which will display an Ajax widget? This is the FB "canvas" option, yes?

- I'll need to include the Google feed JS lib
- I'll need some CSS too.
- The JS will be dynamically changing/animating content on the page (within the iframe).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My Q: Can I create a Facebook App in
>   an iframe which will display an Ajax
>   widget? This is the FB "canvas"
>   option, yes?

It's not, what your are looking for is the Iframe option.

With an iframe you can include everything you need. The canvas option is not as flexible as you probably need it, and it's because of security. With full JS you could potentially do anything with an user account.

The iframe provides a sandbox for facebook.

Comment: Thank you! The app's iframe will be within the Canvas' iframe?  As shown in this blog? http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/adding-iframes-to-facebook-application-2010-static-fbml/   -- Where do you recommend I read more about the "iframe option"? Thanks.